# Compile Error: Declaration of FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter::apply() must be compatible with that of Sensio\Bundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I'm using symfony2. I'm trying to use the Request Body convert listener from FriendsOfSymfony bundle. I have enabled the request converters on sensio_framework_extra and when enabling the body converter:

```
fos_rest:
    body_converter:
            enabled: true
```

I get this exception:

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter::apply() must be compatible with that of Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface::apply() in /var/www/xxx/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/Request/RequestBodyParamConverter.php line 32

in /var/www/xxx/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/Request/RequestBodyParamConverter.php line 32
at ErrorHandler->handleFatalError(object(ExceptionHandler), array('type' => '64', 'message' => 'Declaration of FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter::apply() must be compatible with that of Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface::apply()', 'file' => '/var/www/xxx/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/Request/RequestBodyParamConverter.php', 'line' => '32')) in /var/www/xxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php line 212
```

Here is my full config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

# Friends of Symfony configuration
fos_rest:
    body_converter:
            enabled: true
    routing_loader:
            default_format: json
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'

# Sensio Framework Extra Configuration
sensio_framework_extra:
    request: { converters: true }
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: false }
```

and this is my require libraries on composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.1.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
```

anybody has any ideas?

thanks

Comment: is it possibile that you downloaded an "old" version of that bundle that isn't anymore up to date with Symfony's declaration of that method? It's seems likely

Comment: I have found the issue, there is apparently a conflict when using friendsofsymfony 1.1.0 with sension framework extra bundle 3.0. Downgrading sensio to 2.3.4 solves the conflits. The team of friendsofsymfony is already aware of that issue. So it's the opposite callisto but that helped me find the problem thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. To my eyes was immediatly a problem of that kind so, no problem, no time were used ;)